# How do I store HTML element inside variable in angular and use it in html file

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my TS file I have declare variable as element and inside that written one paragraph tag with some text

```
element ='<p>Something written</p>';
```

I want to show this as paragraph in my html file....
I tried to achieve this using below way in my html file

```
{{element}}
```

But in html it is showing as it is with the `(<p>,</p>)` open and close tags

```
<p>Something written</p>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: <div  [innerHTML]="someHTML"></div>

Comment: should I use something like this ?<div [innerHTML]="element "></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the following example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gnfv9w?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Have a property in your component that contains HTML tags like below;

```
text: string = '<strong>Example of innerHTML in Angular.</strong>';
```

Refer to this property in your template (i.e. HTML file) as follows;

```
<p [innerHTML]="text"></p>
```